# UIScrollView's child moved after keyboard shown

Tags: uiscrollview, keyboard, uitextfield, location, move

i have a problem with UIScrollview after keyboard shown event, apparently my UITextField moved up just like this :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ccBSp.png

and this is after keyboard shown :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/X6NU2.png

I did exactly as the example, this is my code :

```
-(void) keyboardDidShow: (NSNotification *)notif {
if (keyboardVisible) {
    NSLog(@"Keyboard is already visible. Ignoring notofication.");
    return;
}

//The keyboard wasn't visible before
NSLog(@"Resizing smaller for keyboard");

// Get the size of the keyboard.
NSDictionary* info = [notif userInfo];
NSValue* aValue = [info objectForKey:UIKeyboardBoundsUserInfoKey];
CGSize keyboardSize = [aValue CGRectValue].size;

// Resize the scroll view to make room for the keyboard
CGRect viewFrame = self.view.frame;
viewFrame.size.height -= keyboardSize.height;
scrollView.frame = viewFrame;
keyboardVisible = YES;}

-(void) keyboardDidHide: (NSNotification *)notif {
if (!keyboardVisible) {
    NSLog(@"Keyboard is already hidden. Ignoring notification.");
    return;
}

// The keyboard was visible
NSLog (@"Resizing bigger with no keyboard");

//Get the size of the keyboard.
NSDictionary* info = [notif userInfo];
NSValue* aValue = [info objectForKey:UIKeyboardBoundsUserInfoKey];
CGSize keyboardSize = [aValue CGRectValue].size;

// Reset the height of the scroll view to its original value
CGRect viewFrame = self.view.frame;
viewFrame.size.height += keyboardSize.height;

scrollView.frame = viewFrame;
keyboardVisible = NO;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using keyboardWasShown and keyboardWasHidden instead of WillShow and WillHide? Also, I noticed that you are using "UIKeyboardBoundsUserInfoKey" for both Show & Hide. Try "UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey" & "UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey"